# creating grid lines in list view

Tags: winforms

how to create grid lines in list view of windows form while designing

Answer (score 4):

Did you try setting the `GridLines` property to true?

If this didn't seem to work for you, maybe you need to change the `View` property to Details, in order to move the list view to the grid mode.

Comment: thank you Ran, i got result by changing view property to details

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to accept it as the right answer... :)